# Create Method Insert Before Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

I've created an insert after method, and now I have to create an insert before method by modifying my method. What do I need to change to become the insert before method?

```
public void insertAfter(int key, int input){
    Node ndInput = new Node(input, null);
    Node temp = head;
    do{
        if(temp.data == key){
            ndInput.next = temp.next;
            temp.next = ndInput;
            if(ndInput.next == null) tail = ndInput;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }while(temp != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your current code will fail when the list is empty. Also, it would be better to:

- only create the node when the key was found
- make use of the second argument of the `Node` constructor to initialise the `next` property immediately.

So:

```
public void insertAfter(int key, int input) {
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null) { // Loop condition should be here, to deal with empty list
        if (temp.data == key) {
            temp.next = new Node(input, temp.next); // Create here & use 2nd arg
            if (temp == tail) tail = temp.next;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```

To make an `insertBefore`, look for the key in `temp.next` instead of in `temp`. As you still need to deal with the case of an empty list, that can better become a separate condition.

You also need to adapt the head when the inserted node becomes the first. On the other hand, it is no longer necessary to check whether the inserted node becomes the tail, as that is of course impossible:

```
public void insertBefore(int key, int input){
    if (head == null) return; // Add as separate check
    if (head.data == key) { // Case where head needs to refer to new node
        head = new Node(input, head);
        return;
    }
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp.next != null) { // Check whether there is a next node
        if (temp.next.data == key) { // Check data in next node
            temp.next = new Node(input, temp.next);
            break;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```